# What does perl regex separated by commas mean

Tags: perl

In Perl, what does the following expression do:

```
$datarow =~ s/,null/,/g;
```

Comment: [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

Comment: The comma is not significant; it's just a comma character.

Comment: Don't be too hard on the OP. This isn't a standard way a function is usually written, and is confusing when you're not use to it. In PHP, it would be as something like `$datarow = ereg_replace( ",null", ",", $datarow);` That is, there's a clear function (`ereg_replace`), a clear set of arguments (`",null"`, `","`, and `$datarow), and variable that's getting the value set (again `$datarow`). Perl's sed/awk construction can be very hard to understand if you're not a Unix person.

Answer (score 6):

`s/pattern/replacement/` is a command that tells perl to replace the first occurrence of `pattern` with `replacement`.

`s/pattern/replacement/g` causes the command to replace all occurrences, not just the first one.

What your code does is it finds all occurrences of `,null` and replaces them with `,` (it deletes the `null` after each comma).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple replacement command:

```
$string =~ s/find/replace/;
```

In the above, the variable `$string` is being changed. The first instance of the string `find` will be replaced with `replace`.<sup>1</sup>

Adding a `g` on the end means *global*, and that it will replace all instances of `find` with `replace`.

In your command the variable `$datarow` is being changed. All instances of `,null` are being replaced with just a comma. Try the following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $datarow = "this,that,null,this,that,null,this,this,that";
$datarow =~ s/,null/,/g;
say "Datarow is equal to `$datarow'";
```

Go ahead and try this program. It should output:

```
Datarow is equal to `this,that,,this,that,,this,this,that'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I've simplified here. The `find` is not just a string of letters and numbers, but a [regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). Regular expression is a powerful concept, but arcane concept that most developers don't fully comprehend. However, here none of the magic incantations of regular expressions are being used, so this is just describing the literal `,null` string.

Still, you should take the time to look at the [Regular Expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) tutorial that's included in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, the `s/` after `=~` means you're doing a replace (as opposed to `m/` after `=~` which is a match evaluation), the `,null` is the string you want to replace with `,`, which comes after the middle `/`, and the `/g` means it's a global replace, otherwise it'll just replace the first ocurrence...